# Browser Link JavaScript breaks on debugging WebForms project - Expected Identifier

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, browser-link

Upon debugging an ASP.NET WebForms project, I'm shown an error dialog in Visual Studio 2013.

The Browser Link feature includes a handful of pre-generated or runtime-generated JavaScript.

> JavaScript critical error at line xyz column abc in http://local.host/foo/browserLink\n\nSCRIPT1010:
>
> Expected Identifier

This is on setting the line `label.for = id;`

How can I avoid this error?

- Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate
- IE 11
- Windows 8.1 Pro

[image]

Comment: I've just started getting the same issue with a project that reported no issues with VS2012. The issue only occurs in IE7 and below

Answer (score 11):

You'll find the problem is the new Browser link feature.

You can disable it, it solved my issue with IE7 and below when debugging.

[image: Browser Link Menu]

Comment: More info on the feature is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx

Comment: -1 downvote. This answer as it stands adds no new information. I literally created the tag for Browser Link. The title of the question literally starts with "Browser Link". Disabling BL doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @p.campbell This clearly shows how to disable the Browser Link and solve the issue. There are no other accepted answers and your post does not describe how the issue is fixed!!! This should not be downvoted

Answer (score 1):

**for** is a reserved word. You either have to choose another name or do label["for"] = id;

IE doesn't accept reserved javascript words.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the entry below to web.config resolved the issue for me.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key ="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
```